# Java Date TIME Format AM/PM Configuration

Tags: java, simpledateformat

I am facing problems some while formatting the date:

Date : 11/06/2020 04:14:20

Date Format:**dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss a**

Exception:

> java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "11/06/2020 04:14:20"

Following is the code

> `Blockquote`

```
public String getFormatDate(String inputDate) {
        String strDate = "";        
        try {           
            DateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd, yyyy hh:mm:ss a");
            DateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss a");
            Date date1 = inputFormat.parse(inputDate);
            strDate = outputFormat.format(date1);           
        }catch( Exception exe) {
            exe.printStackTrace();
            logger.error( "[ERROR] getFormatDate:. ", exe );
        } 
        return strDate;     
    }
```

> `Blockquote`

Any help would be greatly appeciated.

Comment: share your code

Comment: Is date is in string ?

Comment: Yes this date is in String

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDateTime` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: @OleV.V. Still, many people use `Date` and know that it's outdated

Comment: Yes, @Eklavya, that’s the problem. Their problem. And the problem of those who need to maintain their code after them.

Comment: In `04:14:20`, is the `04` hour of day (00–23) or hour within AM or PM (01-12), and in the latter case, how are we supposed to know whether it’s AM or PM?

Comment: You are not passing the am/pm part so therefore it is giving you the error.

Comment: @mousif80 Yes that was the issue, i have updated the source date and  add AM/PM part. Its working. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check this code you have to pass the am/pm part too with the date string value as your format is expecting that.

```
//String date = "11/06/2020 04:14:20";
String date = "11/06/2020 04:14:20 am";
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss a");
```

https://ideone.com/3nibwJ

Answer (score 2):

### Use proper date-time objects for your dates and times

For the vast majority of purposes you should not keep your date and time in a string and should not convert your date and time from a string in one format to a string in another format. Keep your date and time in a `ZonedDateTime` or `LocalDateTime` object.

When you are required to accept string input, parse that input into a date-time object immediately. I am using and recommending java.time, the modern Java date and time API:

```
    DateTimeFormatter inputFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/uuuu HH:mm:ss");
    String input = "11/06/2020 04:14:20";
    LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(input, inputFormatter);
    System.out.println(dateTime);
```

Output so far is:

> 2020-06-11T04:14:20

Since there is no AM or PM in your string, I have assumed that 04:14:20 was the time *of day* from 00:00:00 through 23:59:59. If you intended otherwise, you need to explain how.

Only when you need to give string output, format your date and time back into a string of appropriate format:

```
    DateTimeFormatter outputFormatter = DateTimeFormatter
            .ofPattern("MMMM dd, yyyy hh:mm:ss a", Locale.ENGLISH);
    String output = dateTime.format(outputFormatter);
    System.out.println(output);
```

> June 11, 2020 04:14:20 AM

Do provide a locale for the formatter so Java knows which language to use for the month name and the AM/PM indicator.

### What went wrong in your code?

Your string has no AM nor PM: `11/06/2020 04:14:20`. Yet your format pattern string requires an AM/PM marker in the end. This is what format pattern letter `a` signifies. So your string wasn’t in the format that you required. This was the reason for the exception that you observed.

### Link

[Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks All for your help:

I have changed the source date "11/06/2020 04:14:20" to "06/11/2020 04:14:20 PM", and then after perform follwoing steps, its working for me:

> Blockquote

```
DateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss a");
inputFormat.setTimeZone( TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC") );                                     
Date dDate = inputFormat.parse( srcDate );                      
String strDeDate = formatDateToString( dDate, "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss a", "IST" );


public String formatDateToString(Date date, String format,String timeZone) {


    if (date == null) return null;

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(format);

    if (timeZone == null || "".equalsIgnoreCase(timeZone.trim())) {
        timeZone = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeZone().getID();
    }

    sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(timeZone));

    return sdf.format(date);
}
```

> Blockquote